# Ubuntu-20.04 - C header files matching your running kernel were not found

Tags: 20.04, kernel, vmware, vmware-workstation

On `Ubuntu-20.04LTS` have installed `VMWare workstation` successfully. When i tried to launch, it shows below error.

[image: Error]

The below workaround couldn't help.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade --yes
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade --yes 
sudo apt-get install build-essential dkms

cd /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build/include/linux
sudo ln -s ../generated/utsrelease.h
sudo ln -s ../generated/autoconf.h
sudo ln -s ../generated/uapi/linux/version.h
```

`linux-headers-5.4.0-91-generic` is already the newest version `(5.4.0-91.102)` installed.

```
$ sudo vmware-modconfig --console --install-all
[AppLoader] GLib does not have GSettings support.

(process:31113): GLib-CRITICAL **: 14:51:49.338: g_file_test: assertion 'filename != NULL' failed
Failed to setup build environment.
```

Currently installed vmware workstation version as follows,

```
$ vmware --version
VMware Workstation 16.2.1 build-18811642
```

Here what I'm missing? And what precisely is vmware looking for?

Answer (score 1):

try the following:

```
 sudo apt install --reinstall linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, It was found that our IT-Department booted the OS kernel with lower kernel version what `vmware - 16.2.1` was expected is latest higher kernel version.

Comment: @user4948798 How did IT or you resolve this?

Comment: Hello, Yes initially our local IT team was booted with lower kernal. After booting in latest kernel it started working fine.